# Resize width of text box in datagrid during edit and fix datagrid cell width

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one data grid which contains a column which contains long string values. When I edit it, the text box which appears is very small. I want to increase the length of text box.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a TemplateColumn? This allows you to customise your layout in edit/view/insert modes.

See sample below:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<% Eval("MyValue") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEdit" runat="server" Text='<% Bind("MyValue") %>' Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code it will help you:

```
 private void AdjustDataGridTextBoxWidth(DataGrid GridName, string SubControlType, Unit Width, int RowsCount, TextBoxMode TBMode, FontUnit FontSize)
    {
        if (SubControlType == "TextBox")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridName.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int o = 1; o < GridName.Items[i].Cells.Count; o++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < GridName.Items[i].Cells[o].Controls.Count; x++)
                    {
                        if (GridName.Items[i].Cells[o].Controls[x].GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")
                        {
                            TextBox GridTextBox = (TextBox)GridName.Items[i].Cells[o].Controls[x];

                            GridTextBox.Width = Width;

                            GridTextBox.Rows = RowsCount;

                            GridTextBox.TextMode = TBMode;

                            GridTextBox.Font.Size = FontSize;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 Your code failed to compile in Visual Studio 2010 (VB.NET project). There were 23 errors.

Comment: You haven't mention that your project is in VB. I have given the code for C#.